# Creating a Binary Matrix given specific proportion or number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a smarter solution to this problem.

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.64], [2, 0.85], [3, 0.20]], columns=['User', 'Number'])
print(df) 
╔══════╦════════════╗
║ User ║ Number     ║
╠══════╬════════════╣
║    1 ║ 3          ║
║    2 ║ 4          ║
║    3 ║ 2          ║
╚══════╩════════════╝
```

Given the number for every row I'd like to create a binary matrix for 5 values, e.g.:

```
[[0  1  0  1  1],
 [1  1  0  1  1],
 [0  0  1  0  1]]
```

The way I solved it:

```
def rand_bin_array(K, N):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    arr[:int(K)]  = 1
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

temp = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp.append(rand_bin_array(df['Number'].iloc[i],5))
```

Is there efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why is your `Number` column in the definition `df = pd.DataFrame` different from the printout? Which one is correct?

Comment: @QuangHoang miss spelling, sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way without a for loop, but you can avoid `shuffle` and `append`.

```
n = 5
ks = [3, 4, 2] # "n choose k"

# Initiate random generator
rng = np.random.default_rng()

# Compute indices
nrange = np.arange(n)
indices = [rng.choice(nrange, size=k, replace=False) for k in ks]

# Fill an array at indices
arr = np.zeros((len(ks), n))
for line, idxs in zip(arr, indices):
    line[idxs] = 1
```

output:

```
>>> arr
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Or you can avoid the second for loop by constructing better indices:

```
indices_col = np.concatenate(indices)
indices_row = np.concatenate([np.full(len(row), i) for i, row in enumerate(indices)])

arr = np.zeros(len(ks), n)
arr[indices_row, indices_col] = 1
```

But I tested it and it is actually slower.

Comment: As this speed up the running time, I'll accept it as the correct one!